# ONELINER which print system groups and their identifiers, for all groups whose identifiers start with '1'

Tags: linux, bash, unix, ubuntu

I have to write an ONELINER which print system groups and their identifiers, for all groups whose identifiers start with '1'.

These are some examples of the groups in my system :

```
fuse:x:105:
messagebus:x:106:
ssl-cert:x:107:
lpadmin:x:108:piciu
scanner:x:109:saned
mlocate:x:110:
ssh:x:111:
utempter:x:112:
avahi-autoipd:x:113:
rtkit:x:114:
saned:x:115:
whoopsie:x:116:
avahi:x:117:
lightdm:x:118:
nopasswdlogin:x:119:
bluetooth:x:120:
colord:x:121:
pulse:x:122:
pulse-access:x:123:
piciu:x:1000:
sambashare:x:124:piciu
howard:x:1001:
penny:x:1002:
leonard:x:1003:
sheldon:x:1004:
```

I have to print: fuse 105 messagebus 106 ssl-cert 107 etc etc etc leonard 1003 sheldon 1004

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a very simple awk script as

```
$ awk -F: '$3 ~ /^1/' input
fuse:x:105:
messagebus:x:106:
ssl-cert:x:107:
lpadmin:x:108:piciu
scanner:x:109:saned
mlocate:x:110:
ssh:x:111:
utempter:x:112:
avahi-autoipd:x:113:
rtkit:x:114:
saned:x:115:
whoopsie:x:116:
avahi:x:117:
lightdm:x:118:
nopasswdlogin:x:119:
bluetooth:x:120:
colord:x:121:
pulse:x:122:
pulse-access:x:123:
piciu:x:1000:
sambashare:x:124:piciu
howard:x:1001:
penny:x:1002:
leonard:x:1003:
sheldon:x:1004:
awk -F: '$3 ~ /^1/' input
fuse:x:105:
messagebus:x:106:
ssl-cert:x:107:
lpadmin:x:108:piciu
scanner:x:109:saned
mlocate:x:110:
ssh:x:111:
utempter:x:112:
avahi-autoipd:x:113:
rtkit:x:114:
saned:x:115:
whoopsie:x:116:
avahi:x:117:
lightdm:x:118:
nopasswdlogin:x:119:
bluetooth:x:120:
colord:x:121:
pulse:x:122:
pulse-access:x:123:
piciu:x:1000:
sambashare:x:124:piciu
howard:x:1001:
penny:x:1002:
leonard:x:1003:
sheldon:x:1004:
```

**What it does?**

- `-F:` sets the field seperator as `:`
- `'$3 ~ /^1/'` checks if the third field, id begins with a `1`

Comment: Thank you so much!! I found something about awk command but I didn't know how to implement. Thank you again !